# Conditional Plotting (cannot use ggplot)

Tags: r, graph, subset

I am  trying to graph a subset using `with()` and `points()`. This is what I have so far:

```
with(d0, plot(d0$pct_phd,d0$tuition))
with(subset(d0, d0$public.private == 0), points(d0$pct_phd, d0$tuition, col = "blue"))
```

[image: This is what it looks like]

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the code is reproducible because we don't have the sample input data associated with `d0`. You should try saving up the subset output and use that saved df as input to points.

Comment: Does this work? `points(tuition ~ pct_phd, data = d0, subset = (public.private == 0), col = "blue")`

Comment: @Gregor I really appreciate your contribution, you were indeed right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll move my comment to an answer:

The point of `with` is that you **don't** need to use `data$column` for the rest of the call, you can refer to the columns directly. Similarly for subset.

```
with(subset(d0, public.private == 0), points(pct_phd, tuition, col = "blue"))
```

`d0$pct_phd` explicitly uses the full column from the original data, overriding the subset being used in `with`. This is why your attempt didn't work.